# New download of Kafka already contains the old topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I was working with a Kafka download pack and was following the Kafka getting started guide. Thus, I created a sample topic called **test**.

Then when I wanted to try setting some access control lists using the **kafka-acls.sh** script. For some reason, I did not find that script inside the bin directory of my kafka pack.

So, I downloaded a fresh kafka pack from their website to check and this script was available. *(I don't know why or how it wasn't there in the earlier pack)*

However, when I started kafka from my new pack and tried to create the same topic **test**, I get an error saying that the topic already exists.

I am trying to figure out how this is possible even with a freshly downloaded instance? Does kafka save topics in some common directory or something?

Shabir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. I figured that if the topics are persisted even across different bundles of Kafka then it must be stored in some place in disk other than the bundle itself.

A little bit of searching proved that the **zookeeper** stores its details in the directory pointed to by **dataDir** inside the **zookeeper.properties** file which is by default */tmp/zookeeper*.

Once I deleted this folder and started a fresh Kafka pack all previous topics were gone and it behaved like a **new fresh pack**.

Thanks
Shabir